# Populate textbox2 based on Textbox1 autocomplete selection?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

How can I populate textbox2 based on an autocomplete textbox1 selected value using ajax? If I used the text change event on the autocomplete textbox it fires when scrolling through the list? Somehow I need to capture the selected item?

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function getSelected() {
      alert($get("<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").value);
  }
</script>



   <td class="style7" colspan="3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="97px" 
            Width="679px"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that there is no server-side event in the `AutoCompleteExtender` that is raised when the user clicks on an item in the drop down list, but there is a client-side event available called `OnClientItemSelected`. This `OnClientItemSelected` property can then be bound to a JavaScript function which can then call back to the server-side.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="486px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" 
    DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="AutoComplete.asmx" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="2" UseContextKey="true" ContextKey="StateDropDown" 
    CompletionListElementID="autocompleteDropDownPanel" OnClientItemSelected="PostBackAutoCompleteChoice()">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function PostBackAutoCompleteChoice() {
        __doPostBack('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>', '');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks how do I then populate textbox2 with this value?

Comment: I added it up top, I can now get the data to copy to that box but I just need to get the ID somehow